# what is the difference between google direction service api and direction api?

Tags: google-maps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

These two api are very similar. the seconds one has a rate limit for free users. but the first one doesn't mention any limit in the api document. so are they the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

The [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) is a [web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/), returns data in either JSON or XML formats, intended to be used by servers or mobile devices that can't use the javascript API.

The [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) is the same data built into the javascript API.  You should use it it you are using the javascript API.

Answer (score 0):

The **API** is accessed using a URL exclusively by HTTP methods. There is a daily and per-second query limit.

The **Service** is a JavaScript library that interfaces with the API and various loaded maps in the document. There is a per-second query limit, but performance is generally better with the API in terms of getting data in short amounts of time.

Use the API for anything non-JavaScript; use the Service in the JavaScript language. There can be CORS errors by attempting to use the API in JavaScript.

Query limits:

> Users of the free API:
>
> - 2500 directions requests per 24 hour period.
> - Up to 8 waypoints allowed in each request. Waypoints are not available for transit directions.
> - 2 requests per second.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Limits

The Service has comparable limits, except it has no daily limit.